# Comparing 2 Groups with Meta-Analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I have n exposures, and 2n estimates. Each exposure produces an estimate for men and an estimate for women. I want to know if the effects are the same for both sexes. People tell me I can use the metafor package in R, the rma function to examine this, but how do I interpret the output? Am I looking at Cochran's Q, at the Q p-value, or something else?
What signifies "no difference between men and women"?

Comment: I don't know what you will do in R (as I don't use it often), but in general you can create two subgroups and review the p-value for differences between the subgroups. Borenstein and Higgins. Prev Sci (2013) 14:134–143.